# Part of data didn't populate in Dynamo DB

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I created a lambda function

```
console.log('starting function');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'ap-northeast-1'});

exports.handle = function(e, ctx, callback) {
  console.log('processing event: %j', e);
  var params ={
    Item: {
        "name":e.name,
        "email":e.email
    },

    TableName:'SignUp'
  };

  docClient.put(params, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            callback(err,null);
        }else{
            callback(null,data);
        }
  });

}
```

I configured a post method on my api gateway, and it works fine, but after I tested it, I found that only email item which I defined as my primary key got populated in my db, there is no name item and data.Didn't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is a reserved word in DynamoDB:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

You should change it to something unique like `myName`.